# force linux kernel to run code without preempting

Tags: linux-kernel, preemptive

I'm writing a Linux kernel(android Linux kernel) module. I have  a general question . is it possible to force kernel run a part of code in non-preemptive mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap the code in `preempt_disable();` / `preempt_enable();`.  Note that this does not block interrupts.